# Parse issue while adding dependency for AFNetworking using cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am new to 3rd party library in Xcode. Added `AFNetworking` dependency using cocoapods, but it is giving parse issue unknown type name `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` and other parse issues like `cannot combine with previous (error) declaration specifier`, `expected a type`, `expected ')'` in `AFURLResponseSerialization.h` and in `AFURLRequestSerialization.h` header file. According to other answer, i tried by removing `iOS version dependency` by commenting this line `platform :ios, '7.0'` but still got the same error. For better understanding of my condition i am attaching the `screenshot`[image]. Any help ll be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried removing the pod, running pod install, and then added it again and running pod install?

Comment: i have tried this `removed pod>deleted workspace>cleaned project> again added pod> run install`.

Comment: Are you using XCODe 7?

Comment: nop Mitchell, Xcode6.2

Comment: It will not support the Swift 2.0 <> Objective-C interop stuff such as null and generics. Can you either A) Use Xcode 7.x or B) use a previous version of AFNetworking such as from August?

Comment: I know pod 'AFNetworking',    '~> 1.3.4' works with Xcode 6.2 on a legacy project here

Comment: i am using Objective-c, can u specify the version number?

Comment: if you wish to use objective-c generics and the new syntax stuff you need Xcode 7 (ideally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an old version (in your Podfile) such as:

```
pod 'AFNetworking',             '~> 1.3.4'
```

Or update your Xcode to preferably 7 as this stuff all came in with Objective-C / Swift interoperability

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of your XCode. Those nullability annotations are available from 6.3

Comment: So, i have to update Xcode, isn't there any other workaround?

Comment: Or use the older version of AFNetworking, as @Mitchell Currie suggested